# Issue with JSON and Swift - \u00c3\u00a9 Ã© instead of é

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to display some JSON data on my iOS app but I am having an issue with displaying it correctly using Swift.

When I use the normal `JSONSerializer` for \u00c3\u00a9 i get Ã© but I want to display é. I don't understand if it is an issue with say using UTF-16 rather than UTF-8 or something else?

Does anyone have any suggestions how I would convert \u00c3\u00a9 straight to é in Swift, from a JSON received from an API.

Comment: Your issue is serializing or deserializing the JSON?

Comment: I think a concrete code example would maybe help narrow it down so people have a better idea about the circumstances...

Comment: `\uNNNN` escape sequences use UTF-16, so "\u00c3\u00a9" *is* "Ã©". In other words, the server produces wrong JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which encoding you're using, but this code works for both `.utf8` and `.utf16`:

```
let jsonString = "{\"foo\": \"áéíóú\"}"
let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf16)!

do {
    let object = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let dict = object as? [AnyHashable: Any], let text = dict["foo"] as? String {
        print("Extracted text: \(text)")
    }
}
catch let e {
    // TODO: Handle error
    print("Error processing JSON: \(e)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**was the same problem. Necessary  use this code, it works:**

```swift
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: params) 
.responseJSON{ response in 
guard let data = response.data else {return}
do {
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary 
let json = jsonResult["response_goods"] as! [[String:String]]
print(json) } catch let err as NSError {print(err)
}
}
```

---